# Show whether the sequence is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

How can I show that $x_n= \sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})+\frac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy Sequence and if it is not, finding a subsequence which is a Cauchy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a "problem statement question" which lacks details and motivation, and as such is not likely to be very well received by the community. Please provide more [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) which will show your work so far and let us understand how you can be helped to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{equation}
     \label{eq:aqui-le-mostramos-como-hacerle-la-llave-grande}
     \sin(\frac{n\pi}{3}) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
  (-1)^k\frac{\sqrt3}{2}      & \mathrm{if\ } n=3k+1\;, n=3k+2  \\
   0     & \mathrm{if\ } n=3k\; 
        \end{array}
      \right.
   \end{equation}
So there are three subsequences which have different limits, so the original sequence cannot be convergent, hence it cannot be Cauchy. For example the subsequence $x_{3k}=\frac{1}{3k}$ is Cauchy because it converges to zero

Comment: This is a "problem statement question" with no work shown and generally lacking context. As per [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) the first action should be to engage with the OP and clarify those details.